# Gui automation testing

Tags: windows, tcl

I am a student and I am interesting in programming in TCL. For a start, I am interested in Wi-fi. I have connected my USB wireless stick into my access point using my webpage (gui) via WPS manually and it works perfectly, so I want to do it automatically. It is required to program it using TCL. I have no idea on how to start. Can someone help me out with a simple test case. 
Hint: On my webpage I have a button Start PBC and on my USB stick I have a WPS button as well.

Best regards
Dirk

Comment: Perhaps google is a good start

Comment: Ok, to summarize (what I have understood and think it is important): you have a webpage that you want to automate. (aka: if xyz happens/if the script is executed, "press" the button on the website). Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You van try selenium or iMacro. The first one works quite well.